# Why does the screen turn white before animations occur?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation, css

I made a new Google Chrome Extension that does Google's "Barrel Roll" and other cool effects using JQuery and CSS3. However, the screen always flashes (turns white) for less than a second before the animations occur. Why is this?

The extension can be downloaded here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lhokhgkogpghngcflpackepikbjejhkf

```js
function effect_barrel_roll() { $('body').addClass('barrel_roll');
setTimeout("$('body').removeClass('barrel_roll')", 4000); }
```

```css
body.barrel_roll { 
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s ease; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

Comment: Don't ask people to download and install a potentially unsafe browser extension. Please post your code instead.

Comment: <script>
function effect_barrel_roll() {
 $('body').addClass('barrel_roll');
  setTimeout("$('body').removeClass('barrel_roll')", 4000);
}</script>

<style>
body.barrel_roll {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s ease;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
} </style>

Answer (score 0):

You may need to fade out the previous contents before the new contents are shown. I faced same problem creating a [website](http://test.aiesec.my/), when I was changing page contents using Ajax and JavaScript.

Before I get the content I added this code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "parts/" + part + ".html", true);

$("#" + id).fadeOut(500);

xmlhttp.send();
```

It fades out previous contents before showing new contents.